# Export Netcdf variable to text using matlab

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I am a newbie with netcdf files and have been trying to export one of the variables from netcdf .nc format to a text file (ascii etc) using MATLAB.

I am able to read the netcdf file using `nc_dump`, and get the variable using `nc_varget`.
But when I try saving the variable (which is 4D double), it does not saves a 4D file, instead it saves just the values in that particular variable.

My code:

```
nc_dump('filename.nc')
var1 = nc_varget('filename.nc','var1');
var2 = nc_varget('filename.nc','var2');
var3 = nc_varget('filename.nc','var3');
var4 = nc_varget('filename.nc','var4');
var5 = nc_varget('filename.nc','var5');
for i = 1:length(var1)
for j = 1:length(var2)
for k = 1:length(var3)
for l = 1:length(var4)
for m = 1:length(var5)
data(i,j,k,l,m) = [var1(i), var2(j), var3(k), var4(l), var5(i,j,k,l)];
end
end
end
end
end
dlmwrite(‘data.txt’, data)
```

Output from nc_dump:

```
nc_dump('geoschem_nestedNA_10_20041010.nc')

NetCDF-3 Classic geoschem_nestedNA_10_20041010.nc {

dimensions:
lon = 151 ;
lat = 121 ;
lev = 37 ;
time = UNLIMITED ; (7 currently)


variables:

    // Preference 'PRESERVE_FVD':  false,
// dimensions consistent with ncBrowse, not with native MATLAB netcdf package.
single lon(lon), shape = [151]
    lon:long_name = "Longitude" ;
    lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
single lat(lat), shape = [121]
    lat:long_name = "Latitude" ;
    lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
single lev(lev), shape = [37]
    lev:long_name = "Eta Centers" ;
    lev:units = "sigma_level" ;
single time(time), shape = [7]
    time:long_name = "Time" ;
    time:units = "hours since 1985-1-1 00:00:0.0" ;
    time:delta_t = "0000-00-00 03:00:00" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__NOx(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__NOx:long_name = "NOx tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__NOx:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__ACET(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__ACET:long_name = "ACET tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__ACET:units = "ppbC" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SO2(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SO2:long_name = "SO2 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SO2:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SO4(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SO4:long_name = "SO4 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SO4:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__NH4(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__NH4:long_name = "NH4 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__NH4:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__NIT(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__NIT:long_name = "NIT tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__NIT:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__BCPI(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__BCPI:long_name = "BCPI tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__BCPI:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__OCPI(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__OCPI:long_name = "OCPI tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__OCPI:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__BCPO(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__BCPO:long_name = "BCPO tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__BCPO:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__OCPO(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__OCPO:long_name = "OCPO tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__OCPO:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__ALPH(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__ALPH:long_name = "ALPH tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__ALPH:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__LIMO(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__LIMO:long_name = "LIMO tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__LIMO:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__ALCO(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__ALCO:long_name = "ALCO tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__ALCO:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOG1(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG1:long_name = "SOG1 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG1:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOG2(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG2:long_name = "SOG2 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG2:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOG3(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG3:long_name = "SOG3 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG3:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOG4(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG4:long_name = "SOG4 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG4:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOG5(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG5:long_name = "SOG5 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOG5:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOA1(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA1:long_name = "SOA1 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA1:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOA2(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA2:long_name = "SOA2 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA2:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOA3(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA3:long_name = "SOA3 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA3:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOA4(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA4:long_name = "SOA4 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA4:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SOA5(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA5:long_name = "SOA5 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SOA5:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__DST1(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__DST1:long_name = "DST1 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__DST1:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__DST2(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__DST2:long_name = "DST2 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__DST2:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__DST3(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__DST3:long_name = "DST3 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__DST3:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__DST4(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__DST4:long_name = "DST4 tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__DST4:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SALA(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SALA:long_name = "SALA tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SALA:units = "ppbv" ;
single IJ_AVG_S__SALC(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    IJ_AVG_S__SALC:long_name = "SALC tracer" ;
    IJ_AVG_S__SALC:units = "ppbv" ;
single DAO_FLDS__PARDF(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    DAO_FLDS__PARDF:long_name = "GMAO PARDF field" ;
    DAO_FLDS__PARDF:units = "W/m2" ;
single DAO_FLDS__PARDR(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    DAO_FLDS__PARDR:long_name = "GMAO PARDR field" ;
    DAO_FLDS__PARDR:units = "W/m2" ;
single DAO_FLDS__TS(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    DAO_FLDS__TS:long_name = "GMAO TS field" ;
    DAO_FLDS__TS:units = "K" ;
single TIME_SER__D_LAI(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    TIME_SER__D_LAI:long_name = "Daily LAI" ;
    TIME_SER__D_LAI:units = "m2/m2" ;
single BIOGSRCE__ISOP(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__ISOP:long_name = "ISOP emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__ISOP:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__MONOT(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__MONOT:long_name = "MONOT emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__MONOT:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__MBO(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__MBO:long_name = "MBO emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__MBO:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__APINE(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__APINE:long_name = "APINE emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__APINE:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__BPINE(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__BPINE:long_name = "BPINE emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__BPINE:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__LIMON(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__LIMON:long_name = "LIMON emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__LIMON:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__SABIN(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__SABIN:long_name = "SABIN emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__SABIN:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__MYRCN(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__MYRCN:long_name = "MYRCN emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__MYRCN:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__CAREN(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__CAREN:long_name = "CAREN emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__CAREN:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;
single BIOGSRCE__OCIMN(time,lev,lat,lon), shape = [7 37 121 151]
    BIOGSRCE__OCIMN:long_name = "OCIMN emissions" ;
    BIOGSRCE__OCIMN:units = "atomC/cm2/s" ;


//global attributes:
    :Title = "COARDS/netCDF file created by BPCH2COARDS (GAMAP v2-03+)" ;
    :Model = "GEOS5_47L" ;
    :Delta_Lon = 0.666667 f;
    :Delta_Lat = 0.500000 f;
    :NLayers = 47 d;
    :Start_Date = 20041010 d;
    :Start_Time = 0 d;
    :End_Date = 20041010 d;
    :End_Time = 21 d;
    :Delta_Time = 3 d;
    :Conventions = "COARDS" ;
```

The datafile can be found at the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fnpw71yc60fm6z/geoschem_nestedNA_10_20041010.nc

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Can you post the whole code that you've tried?

Comment: @darthbith just posted the code below.

Comment: The code should go into your original post, not as an answer... you can edit your post by clicking the "Edit" button underneath the tags and above the comments section.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code! Can you also post some sample data?

Comment: Sorry,I am new to this forum, could not figure out how to post a reply with code. The output from nc_dump is posted above now.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for working to make this a better question! Not many people do that, and I hope you'll be able to get some help! If you want to post a file somewhere, people sometimes link to a datafile in their Dropbox or similar account

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with posting a better question. Just posted the link to the data file.

Comment: "it does not saves a 4D file - instead it saves just the values in that particular variable. " - could you clarify further?Your code snippet would write *all* values of the data variable as a single stream of values in the text file. Text files, by themselves, dont have a concept of 'dimensionality'. How do you plan to use the text file? How does that component that is going to use this textfile determine the dimensionality? If you could tell us more as to why you want the textfile, someone might be able to suggest a potentially better solution.

Comment: For e.g. variable IJ_AVG_S__NOx is 4-D with time, lev, lat, lon as the dimensions. So if I ask matlab to print 
IJ_AVG_S__NOx(1,1,1,1) - it will give me the value of IJ_AVG_S__NOx at time=1, lev=1, lat=1, lon=1, which is alright. When you save it, it will only provide IJ_AVG_S__NOx values. 
However, what I want to do is to create  text file, containing columns of time, lev, lat, long and the variable (IJ_AVG_S__NOx), so that for each IJ_AVG_S__NOx, there are corresponding time, lev, lat, lon values. Does it makes more clear?

Comment: Anyone knows anything?? Any scripts / codes out there which does it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the thread but I think this code update should work. 
Instead of using

data(i,j,k,l,m) = [var1(i), var2(j), var3(k), var4(l), var5(i,j,k,l)];

which creates a multi-dimensional matrix, I wanted to create a table with each variable filled in.

THis is probably not the most efficient code (I'm very new, opened Matlab for the first time yesterday new) but I think this code works.

The dataset is created, then overwritten so that memory does not have to be continuously reallocated

```
for n = 2008:2010
name = sprintf('tmax_daily_%d-%d.nc', n, n );
name2 = sprintf('tmax_daily_%d.txt', n);
nc= netcdf.open(name)
data=zeros(2000000000,5);
long3=netcdf.getVar(nc,0);
long=mod((long3+180),360)-180;
lat=netcdf.getVar(nc,1);
height=netcdf.getVar(nc,2);
time=netcdf.getVar(nc,3);
tmax=netcdf.getVar(nc,4);
 row=1;
for i=1:length(long)
for j=1:length(lat)
for k=1:length(height)
for l=1:length(time)
for m=1:length(tmax)
data(row,1)=[long(i)];
data(row,2)=[lat(j)];
data(row,3)=[height(k)];
data(row,4)=[time(l)];
data(row,5)=[tmax(i,j,k,l)];
row=row+1;
end
end
end
end
end

csvwrite(name2,data)
fprintf('%d done\n',n);
clear
end
```